# Android Invite System

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to get usernames from a parse database perhaps by using a query and then sending them an invite in the form of a push notification or email? I want to be able to invite users to edit something but I checked the documentation and can't seem to find anything that is strictly Parse. Everything I've found involves Facebook and/or Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, there is no invite system in Parse. However, it shouldn't be too hard to implement.
You can query the Parse User table for all user id's that match the your need and send them push notifications using Advanced Targeting.
See this for android push notifications:
https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/Android

Comment: I think I got a better understanding of my own question now! Thanks.